# Scrollview wrong scrolling on custom control

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a custom control that looks like this:

[image]

It allows you to pick multiplier from 1 to 10. Inside it is scroll view with multiple UILabels in it. Each label has tag and using the tag I calculate needed positions for label.
The user may either swipe to move this or tap on the number to make it move automatically.

But I have faced the problem - if the view is scrolling and I tap on the number while it is scrolling, it will stop not on the number I tapped on, but on some other number.

When the scroll view is not scrolling taps work fine. Here is relevant code:

This method is needed to stop on the number when it ends scrolling:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{

    NSInteger targetIndex = targetContentOffset->x / (self.frame.size.width / 4.0) ;
    *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake((targetIndex) * (self.frame.size.width / 4.0), targetContentOffset->y);

    if (targetIndex > [self.dataSource numberOfItemsInPicker:self] - 1) {
        targetIndex = [self.dataSource numberOfItemsInPicker:self] - 1;
    }

    if (self.gameName) {
        for (int i=0; i<self.labels.count; i++) {
            UILabel *label = self.labels[i];
            if (i == targetIndex) {
                label.textColor = [GeneralHelper colorForGame:self.gameName];
            }
            else {
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(colorForTextForSmallNumberPicker:)]) {
                    label.textColor = [self.delegate colorForTextForSmallNumberPicker:self];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate smallNumberPickerView:self didPickNumberAtIndex:targetIndex];
    }
}
```

This is the code that determines position of labels in scroll view:

```
- (CGPoint)offsetForIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    return CGPointMake(roundf((self.frame.size.width / 4.) * index), 0.);
}
```

And I think this is the offending code that handles tap gesture recognizer:

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:[self offsetForIndex:recognizer.view.tag - LABELS_START_TAG] animated:YES];

}
```

My ideas what happens is that during scrolling frame is wrong, or positions are wrong, but I have no idea how to handle this. I noticed that when I tap I NSLog target offset and it is wrong, and if it is not scrolling - I will get right offset.
What can I do about this?

Comment: FWIW, if I tap on a scrollview when it is scrolling, I expect my tap to stop the scrollview *and nothing more*. The behaviour you desire, I would find annoying. So I would implement the delegate method for your tap gesture recogniser to refuse touches whilst the scroll view is in motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in calculations. This line:

```
return CGPointMake(roundf((self.frame.size.width / 4.) * index), 0.);
```

It divided by 4 but the labels were actually smaller then 1/4 of the picker, so I got wrong results.